# After migration magento 2 width, height and length does not take decimal values

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, magento-admin

[image]

[image]**decimal values not visible after save in magento 2 after migration and also not able to import attribute with decimal values**

Comment: it maybe is unrelated - but what values where the original values (before saving)?
After our last update, some config values dont change in the backend, but get changed in the database. We had to deploy-static-content to see those changes in the backend first.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check `backend_type` and `backend_model` for those attributes in `eav_attribute`.

Magento doesn't install any default attributes like `width`, `height` or `length` and those attributes can come from some 3rd party shipping extension or customization.

Also please check if you don't have any custom logic for rendering or saving those attributes.

You can update question with information from eav_attribute and also please check saved value in DB for your product in related EAV table.